# Conver char value to variable?

Tags: programming, c

I want to pass the preprocessor values(AT commands) to the Serial.println function. Im trying TCP connection using arduino-SIM900A. I've declared all AT commands to each preprocessor variables like below

```
#define A "AT\r"
#define B "AT+CPIN?\"
...
```

I've assigned all preprocessor variables in char array and pass it into Serial.print using for loop.

```
char varAT[12]={'A','B'....};
for(int i=0;i<=12;i++)
{
Serial.print(varAT[i]);
}
```

Its not printing AT, instead it print preprocessor variable name A. I searched the google how to convert char value to variable, in C there is a function called "eval". Using eval we can acheive, but it wont work in arduino lang. How to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first, `char varAT[12]` indicates an array of 12 characters.

Second, quotes indicate literals - 'A' means, literally, the character 'A'. Variables and constants are without quotes (same way you use  `i`).

I think you mean:

```
char *varAT[12]={A,B....};
```

Also, your constant `B` is invalid - I think you meant for it to end in `\r"`, not `\"`.

Comment: Thanks AMADANON. Its working. but i used char pointer char*. Once again thank you.